# Punctuation, parenthetical elements, confusing

Tags: commas

Could someone please let me know why there is a comma before as and did?

"Anyone who makes the observation, **as** the patriarch of the clan,
Cosimo de’ Medici, **did**, that “every painter paints himself ” is clearly someone
with a deep understanding of creativity."

Comment: Parenthetical phrase

Comment: Commas 1 and 4 could be replaced by dashes, which would simplify in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Parenthetical "Cosimo de’ Medici" within the parenthetical "as the patriarch of the clan did".  Each parenthetical in set off by commas before and after.

> Anyone who makes the observation **[** as the patriarch of the clan **{** Cosimo de’ Medici **}** did **]** that “every painter paints himself ” is clearly someone with a deep understanding of creativity.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the sentence is confusing to the point of incomprehensibility.

It should be

"Anyone who makes the observation, *as did Cosimo de’ Medici, the patriarch of the clan,*  that “every painter paints himself” is clearly someone with a deep understanding of creativity."

“as did Cosimo de’ Medici” is in parentheses

“the patriarch of the clan” is part of the parenthetical clause but in apposition to “Cosimo de’ Medic”

The whole of “as did Cosimo de’ Medici, the patriarch of the clan,” is parenthetical clause and can be omitted.